# Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013, Where are variables defined and edited?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm working on an existing project, the solution contains quite a lot of projects with a lot of dependencies and variables.

I'm struggling to locate any of the variables using the IDE, where will I find these in the IDE?

For example in one of the .vcxproj files there are variables such as:

```
    $(FraenkelPlatformName)
```

Where would I find this in the IDE ?

Edit:
[image: Screen shot of Other Windows available]

Edit 2:
[image: After resetting menus, another shot]

Comment: Does this help (docs for 2013 are not online); https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=vs-2015 ?

Comment: @RichardCritten, thank you, I will look into your link.

Comment: Richard's link can't help, it is not a "common macro".  Use View > Other Windows > Property Manager.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/create-reusable-property-configurations?view=vs-2019

Comment: Do you want to find all references to `$(FraenkelPlatformName)`, its value, or its definition?

Comment: @HansPassant, please see edit, there is no Property Manager window.

Comment: @HansPassant, done that, edited post another screen shot after reset still no Property Manger.

Comment: It's confusing to have both ` Properties Window` and ` Property Manager`. However there is Property Manager in your second image, next to last item in VIEW menu.

Comment: Thank you, now I can see all the variables listed under the User Macros section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, based on the great comments on my post, but no answer posted this is what I need to do:

1. From the **VIEW** top line menu, select **Property Manager**
2. Select a project from the left "Property Manager" panel and expand the node.
3. Open a build folder, Debug or Release and double click on **buildvars**
4. From **Common Properties** select **User Macros**

All the variables are listed here and can be Added or Removed.